# terraform providers causes to TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure

I've been receiving the error
`##[error]TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null`
when running terraform providers as part of a pipeline in Azure Devops. An oddity is this issue occurs only for my apply step. A previous step which also runs providers returns

```
terraform.exe providers
 .
 ├── provider.azurerm ~> 1.33.0
 ├── module.acr
 │   └── provider.azurerm ~> 1.33.0
 ├── module.aks
 │   └── provider.azurerm ~> 1.33.0
 ├── module.rg
 │   └── provider.azurerm ~> 1.33.0
 ├── module.sa
 │   └── provider.azurerm ~> 1.33.0
 └── module.spn
     ├── provider.azuread
     ├── provider.azurerm ~> 1.33.0
     └── provider.random
```

#### EDIT:

Seems like this was an issue with the path referenced in the Terraform step. Changing it to a valid path has fixed the issue.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it after 48 hours

Comment: @gungthar Really thanks for sharing your solution here,you could convert it into an answer. So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like this was an issue with the 'Configuration directory' setting in the Terraform 'Validate and Apply' Release Pipeline step. Changing it to the path containing the build artifacts has fixed the issue.

Comment: I've raised a git hub issue to try and get a more useful error message out of this https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-extensions/issues/880